# « Le quartier où ma maison est situé(e) ne casse pas trois pattes à un canard »

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, genre

I'm trying to say "the area where my house is located is nothing to write home about". Should it be situé (referring to quartier) or située (referring to maison)?
Merci à tous !

Comment: The reasoning is the same whatever the language:  your house is located in an area, this area is nothing to write home about. "Located" refers to the house, "nothing to write about" refers to the area.  The reasoning doesn't change if you put it into French.

Comment: This is not a question about French since OP shows they know how to agree adjectives in gender in French.

Comment: Very simply, you may say "le quartier est quelconque". *Quelconque* refers to  *something that can be found everywhere, without particular quality or value, i.e. nothing remarkable there*.

Comment: FYI in case you don't know who to type « », it's perfectly fine to use " " instead, we do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

"située", since it refers to the "maison" which is of the feminine gender.
However, I would probably say "Le quartier où se trouve ma maison", less of a word-for-word translation.

Comment: Or possibly *où se situe ma maison*, if for some reason you prefer *se situer* to *se trouver*.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see a reason to bring the house into the sentence. I'd write it as "le quartier où j'habite"

Comment: @Circus Except when you rent your house to someone else and you live elsewhere (presumably in a more interesting place) ? Still, it's an interesting remark in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Une  formulation renversée montre l'évidence :
*Ma maison est **située** dans un quartier qui ne casse pas trois pattes à un canard'*.

Pour que le quartier soit '*situé*', il lui faudrait
-soit **un lieu**: :
*Le quartier où se trouve ma maison est ***situé*** en périphérie de la ville ...*
-soit un **qualificatif** faisant de *situé* une qualité :
'*le quartier où se trouve ma maison est **mal situé**, il ne casse pas trois pattes à un canard'.*